# Join two part SQL query into one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, inner-join

This is what I have:

**Query**

```
select
bc.short_desc as cdesc
from
blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_category_link as blpc on bp.post_id = blpc.post_id
inner join blog_category as bc on blpc.cat_id = bc.cat_id
where bp.post_id = 1
```

**Result**

```
----------------
| |cdesc       |
----------------
|1|Top level   |
----------------
|2|Sub level   |
----------------
|3|SubSub level|
----------------
```

**Second query**

```
select
bt.short_desc as tdesc
from
blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_tag_link as blpt on bp.post_id = blpt.post_id
inner join blog_tag as bt on blpt.tag_id = bt.tag_id
where bp.post_id = 1
```

**Second result**

```
----------------
| |tdesc       |
----------------
|1|Tag1        |
----------------
|2|Tag2        |
----------------
```

**The desired result after joining these two queries**

```
----------------------
| |cdesc       |tdesc|
----------------------
|1|Top level   |Tag1 |
----------------------
|2|Sub level   |Tag2 |
----------------------
|3|SubSub level|     |
----------------------
```

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SET @rn1 = 0;
SET @rn2 = 0;

SELECT t1.rId, t1.cdesc, t2.tdesc
FROM 
(select @rn1 := rn1 + 1 AS rId, bc.short_desc as cdesc
from blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_category_link as blpc on bp.post_id = blpc.post_id
inner join blog_category as bc on blpc.cat_id = bc.cat_id
where bp.post_id = 1) t1, 
(select @rn2 := rn2 + 1 AS rId, bt.short_desc as tdesc
from blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_tag_link as blpt on bp.post_id = blpt.post_id
inner join blog_tag as bt on blpt.tag_id = bt.tag_id
where bp.post_id = 1) t2
WHERE t1.rId = t2.rId;
```

For MS SQL server

```
SELECT t1.rId, t1.cdesc, t2.tdesc
FROM 
(select row_number() over(order by bp.post_id) AS rId, bc.short_desc as cdesc
from blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_category_link as blpc on bp.post_id = blpc.post_id
inner join blog_category as bc on blpc.cat_id = bc.cat_id
where bp.post_id = 1) t1, 
(select row_number() over(order by bp.post_id) AS rId, bt.short_desc as tdesc
from blog_post as bp 
left join blog_post_tag_link as blpt on bp.post_id = blpt.post_id
inner join blog_tag as bt on blpt.tag_id = bt.tag_id
where bp.post_id = 1) t2
WHERE t1.rId = t2.rId;
```

Comment: Isn't it `mysql`? I am getting error "Incorrect syntax near ':'"

Comment: It is for mysql.. I have tested it in fiddle.

Comment: `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near ':'.` I'm running on Microsoft SQL Server. Managed to fix and result is same as runing @Jakub Kania answer

Comment: It's nearly there :) It does not return `SubSub total` row as there is no third row in tag table. I can fix from now on :) thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this template, and simply insert the queries from above in as sub-queries for T1 and T2:

```
Select *
from ( 
) T1 
join ( 
) T2  on T2.tdesc = T1.cdesc and T2.Tag1 = T1.TopLevel and T2.Tag2 = T1.SubLevel
```

Comment: thank you for suggestion. `Tag1, Top level` and so on are random names that can be edited and added. Can be hundreds and thousands of them.

Comment: You are joining on hundreds or thousands of unknown fields? How can that be? Then I have simply misunderstood; substitute the actual join field names from the two subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
bc.short_desc AS cdesc, bt.short_desc AS tdesc
FROM
blog_post AS bp
LEFT JOIN blog_post_category_link AS blpc ON bp.post_id = blpc.post_id
INNER JOIN blog_category AS bc ON blpc.cat_id = bc.cat_id
LEFT JOIN blog_post_tag_link AS blpt ON bp.post_id = blpt.post_id
INNER JOIN blog_tag AS bt ON blpt.tag_id = bt.tag_id
WHERE bp.post_id = 1
```

Comment: This returns => `1|Top level|Tag2, 2|Top level|Tag1, 3|Sub level|Tag2, 4|Sub level|Tag1, 5|SubSub level|Tag2, 6|SubSub level|Tag1`

Comment: @Morpheus oh, right you only want to list them...So I think you need to tell what db then.